# Problema con ArrayList| metodo add()|JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo la siguiente clase:

```
 public class EventoPublic{
    String nombre;

    //Constructor
    public EventoPublic(String 
    nombre){

    this.nombre=nombre;
    }


    //Metodo getter
    public String getNombre(){
    return this.nombre;
    }

    //Metodo setter
    public void setNombre(String nombre){

    this.nombre=nombre;
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo en la clase principal esta en el ArrayList que almacena objetos de la clase EventoPublic

```
ArrayList<EventoPublic> evt=new ArrayList<>();

evt.add(new EventoPublic("Nocturno"));

evt.add(new EventoPublic("Carnaval"));

evt.add(new EventoPublic("Hallowen"));
```

Añado esos tres objetos anteriores de la clase EventoPublic

Luego hago un print del nombre de cada objeto dentro del ArrayList

```
//Deberia lanzar : Nocturno
System.out.println(evt.get(0).getNombre();

//Deberia lanzar : Carnaval
System.out.println(evt.get(1).getNombre()

//Deberia lanzar : Hallowen
System.out.println(evt.get(2).getNombre()
```

Pero en la consola me lanza:

Hallowen
Hallowen
Hallowen

Es decir,se esta añadiendo al arraylist siempre el mismo objeto

No entiendo por que‍♂️ si entienden el error agradeceria que me ayudaran.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo funciona correctamente, excepto por el hecho de que tienes algunos errores de falta de caracteres y comas... este es tu codigo corregido:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static class EventoPublic{
        String nombre;

        //Constructor
        public EventoPublic(String 
        nombre){

        this.nombre=nombre;
        }


        //Metodo getter
        public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
        }

        //Metodo setter
        public void setNombre(String nombre){

        this.nombre=nombre;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Main.EventoPublic> evt = new ArrayList<>();

        evt.add(new Main.EventoPublic("Nocturno"));

        evt.add(new Main.EventoPublic("Carnaval"));

        evt.add(new Main.EventoPublic("Hallowen"));

        //Deberia lanzar : Nocturno
        System.out.println(evt.get(0).getNombre());

        //Deberia lanzar : Carnaval
        System.out.println(evt.get(1).getNombre());

        //Deberia lanzar : Hallowen
        System.out.println(evt.get(2).getNombre());

    }
}
```

Para probarlo puedes ir a:

[paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/SxGrtNUc7zZ6UHzqWmLp0g)

donde puedes ejecutar código `Java` directamente en la web, es desde esa pagina web donde probe el codigo.